# Accessing vue instance in controller's function

Tags: vue.js

Controller:

```
Vue.directive('fetch',function(value,scope){
value["url"].isLiteral = true;
qwest.post(value["url"]).then(
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response["CODE"] == 1){
            console.log(response["RESULT"]);
            this.result = response["RESULT"];
            this.error = "";
        }else{
            this.result = "";
            this.error = response["ERROR"];
        }
    }
).catch(
        function(e,response){
            this.error = response["ERROR"];
        }
    );
})
```

Model:

```
var test = new Vue({
el : "#test",
data : {
    code : "",
    result : "",
    error : ""
    }
})
```

So, in this if I use `this.result` it is out of scope, but if I reference it as `test.result` then it is accessed and the value is updated so what would be the generalised way of accessing the vue instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution,
It is possible to use a property available in directive object, it is this.vm which is actually the vue model the for the directive, thus is possible use this.vm and assign it to some variable before invoking the function and thus use the name of the variable to which this.vm was assign as singleton function call.

```
Vue.directive('fetch',function(value){
value["url"].isLiteral = true;
var model = this.vm;
qwest.post(value["url"]).then(
    function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if (response["CODE"] == 1){
            console.log(response["RESULT"]);
            model.result = response["RESULT"];
            model.error = "";
        }else{
            model.result = "";
            model.error = response["ERROR"];
        }
    }
).catch(
        function(e,response){
            model.error = response["ERROR"];
        }
    );
})
```